# Google Map Conflict Php and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, conflict

I am building an application that has the functionality like

3 tabs created using javascript:

1. Mapview
2. ListView
3. Post Events

When I load the page the default action is the loading of Google map with all my events retrieved from database, and it is functioning properly. But when I click on the next post events tab, in that map is loading but it is not visible fully on that space. Its dragging on to one corner.

Can anyone please help me out?

I am new to Google maps in PHP.

The button clicks I have also done are using javascript.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example: Simple Map</title>
  <script src="//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=[My key goes here]" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
        map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    }

    function view_map() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("view_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
        map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script language="javascript">
    function change_div(div_id) {
      document.getElementById('div_1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('div_2').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('div_3').style.display = 'none';
      //alert(div_id);
      document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center">
    <div align="left">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change_div('div_1')">Post Events</a> |
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change_div('div_2')">List Events</a> |
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change_div('div_3')">Map View</a>
    </div>
    <div align="left" id="div_1">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
      <script language="javascript">initialize();</script>
    </div>
    <div align="left" id="div_2" style="display:none">
      List Events
    </div>
    <div align="left" id="div_3" style="display:none">
      <div id="view_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
      <script language="javascript">view_map();</script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its dragging on to one corner, what do you mean by this

Comment: The map is not showing fully on the space alloted for map. Its shrinking on to one side and i want it to be displayed fit for the space.

Comment: have you allowed the width/height for you div to accommodate the size of the map

Comment: Yes i have. You can check in my code. Anyway i'm pasting it here again!    <div id="view_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry i dont realy know, because you api is the older version and i dont have a key and it dosnt work, all i can suggest there are few things

First: place your `view_map();` script block within the `view_canvas` div

```
<div align="left" id="div_3" style="display:none">
  <div id="view_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"><script language="javascript">view_map();</script></div>

</div>
```

Second Another thing is your `change_div()` function it looks kinda biggie.

Lastly May be Uupdate to the newer Map API you don't need a key for it and is more backwards compatible with older browsers.

**Update:**

If you  place for example `view_map()` in

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="change_div('div_3');view_map();">Map View</a>
```

and remove the `<script>view_map()</script>` from within `div_3` should display correctly.

both maps where initialized on startup and couldn't check resize.

Comment: @Neeraj see update to answer above, and delete you comment with you key

Comment: @ David.. Thank you very much dude.. I got it exactly correct.... once again Thank You...